# Calculate Fiscal Year in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to calculate the fiscal year in Snowflake and I am running into issues. The fiscal year that I'm trying to calculate for is from July 1st of the current year to June 30th of the following year.

This is my code so far just to get the beginning date for the fiscal year:

```
CASE WHEN date_part(month,GETDATE()) <= 6
     THEN YEAR(GETDATE())-1
     ELSE try_cast(EXTRACT('year',current_date()) as varchar) + '-07-01' + 
     END AS FISCAL_YEAR_TEST
```

I keep getting this error whenever I try to cast the year extract to a varchar:

```
Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types NUMBER(4,0) and VARCHAR(16777216)
```

Is there any way to get the fiscal year date to work in Snowflake?

Comment: Please share some sample data: What are the right answers?

Comment: I'm just doing the current date as a proof of concept. For today's date, I would expect the date to be '2021-07-01'

Comment: What's the logic? Please add several examples.

Comment: The logic needs to be for the current date for example is that the fiscal year date is '2021-07-01' to '2022-06-30'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want :

```
select case when quarter(current_date()) > 2 
         then date_from_parts(year(current_date()), 07, 01)
         else date_from_parts(year(current_date()) -1, 07, 01)
       end as Fiscalyearbegins
      ,case when quarter(current_date()) > 2 
         then date_from_parts(year(current_date()) +1, 06, 31)
         else date_from_parts(year(current_date()) ,06, 31)
       end as FiscalyearEnds
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for, but I need to have the result to be for a date like 08/01/2021 that the fiscal year is 07/01/2021 to 06/30/2021.

Comment: @Perdue hmm.. you want an specif date to be returned no matter which day of year is? I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. add some example

Comment: Yes, so in my example above, if the date is 08/01/2021, then the fiscal year begin date would be 07/01/2021 and the fiscal year end would be 06/30/2022.

Comment: @Perdue see updated answer

Comment: That's actually the answer I've come up with after playing around with it for a bit. :) Thank you for confirming that I am on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer for end of year March 31

```
YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,case when month(date(your_date)) <= 3 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END, your_date)) as fiscal_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below query:

```
select
    date_trunc(MONTH,add_months(current_date::date, -5))::date as fiscal_start_month,
    last_day(add_months(fiscal_start_month,11))::date fiscal_lastday;
```

You can also replace hardcoded value 5 with variable which makes dynamic.

Comment: This came really close to what I need, but I need it to be more fixed to where if there is a date like 08/01/2021 that the fiscal year will be 07/01/2021 to 06/30/2022.

Answer (score 0):

The logic can be simplified a little by using [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html) to push the year.

```
SELECT
    CalendarDate
    , YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, CalendarDate)) AS FiscalYear
    , DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, CalendarDate)) - 1, 07, 01) FiscalYearBegin
    , DATE_FROM_PARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 6, CalendarDate)), 06, 30) AS FiscalYearEnd
FROM
    (
      SELECT CAST('01/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('02/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('03/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('04/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('05/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('06/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('07/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('08/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('09/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('10/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('11/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
      UNION
      SELECT CAST('12/01/2021' AS DATE) AS CalendarDate
    ) AS Dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
SELECT 'Fin year start' as Caption,
    (DATEADD (year,
        DATEDIFF (month, '1-Jul-1901', GETDATE()) /12, '1-Jul-1901')) as TheDate

UNION

SELECT 'Fin year end' as Caption,
    (DATEADD (year, 1, DATEADD(d, -1,
    (DATEADD (year, DATEDIFF (month, '1-Jul-1901', GETDATE())/12, '1-Jul-1901'))))) as TheDate
```

The maths here is simply

1. Work out the number of months from a fixed financial year starting point, e.g. 1-Jul-1901
2. Divide by 12 to get the integer number of years; i.e. whole years completed
3. Then that is our start of financial year.
4. Next, add a year and subtract a day to get the end of the current financial year.

While there are other solutions above, this one (I feel) lends itself better to assigning to variables and adjusting to give previous or future financial year start/end dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
SET THISDATE = CURRENT_DATE();
SELECT
    DATEADD(MONTH,-6,DATE_TRUNC(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH,6,$THISDATE))) AS START_OF_FY
    ,DATEADD(MONTH,-6,LAST_DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,6,$THISDATE),YEAR)) AS END_OF_FY
    ,CONCAT('FY',YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,6,$THISDATE))) AS FY_GROUP
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).